# File sometimes doesn't download from my website

Tags: internet-explorer

When I attempt to download this file, sometimes it only downloads about 700KB (the file is 40MB) then I get the message that the download is complete. If I try to download the file again, it works properly.

The problem seems prevalent in IE, although I've had it happen in Chrome sometimes too.

I have the following code:

```
<input type="button" 
    value="Agree to Terms and Download" 
    onClick="location.href='/downloads/setup.exe';" />
```

If it matters, this is over a secure connection.

I also tried zipping the file, and had the same issues.

Comment: Anything in the logs? Any specific directives for that vhost/path? What's serving the file, apache or php? You're giving us little to work with here.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a server issue, what server are you using?

Comment: An apache server

Comment: Check your error_log for errors. I don't have a solution yet, but HTTP analysers like [HttpFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6647/) could be useful here.
Look for the Content-Length response header.
It should always match the filesize.

I think your server crashed during the download; apache stops serving and your browser thinks it's done.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to set up some web monitoring so you get some better statistics on the issue. Maybe that reveals a pattern. Try  e. g. with a free account at AlertFox: [Monitor file downloads](http://wiki.alertfox.com/FAQ#Q:_How_can_I_verify_that_a_downloaded_file_is_correct.3F)